# SQL capture output from Merge into temp table

Tags: sql-server, merge

I followed this code from another post:

```
MERGE [Destination] AS d
USING (SELECT * FROM #SourceForMerge) AS s
      ON d.PrimaryKey = s.PrimaryKey

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    -- UPDATE columns

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    -- INSERT columns

OUTPUT
    -- columns
INTO
    #OutputTempTable
```

I was using an actual table before (with a `INSERT INTO <Table>` before the merge, but I added a foreign key, which is not allowed. So I am trying to import into a temp table , then into my main table. The documentation says I can use a temp table and that the column list is not mandatory. However , I can't even get it to work , even if I declare the columns.

```
OUTPUT @BatchId , $action into #OutputTempTable ( batchid, what )  ;
```

I am getting error

> Invalid object name '#OutputTempTable'

I know I am probably missing something basic, but been a long week.

Thanks

Comment: _from another post_ Link it so everyone sees exactly what you see. Reducing a query to pseudo-code is often very misleading and prone to typos. Then show a complete query that demonstrates your current approach which produces the error.

Comment: _but I added a foreign key, which is not allowed_ That is not accurate - there is no requirement to have or NOT have a FK in the output table. But the database engine will not automatically create the temp table - if that is was you are expecting. Your code must create that table before attempting to use it in your MERGE statement.

Comment: You need to actually create the table with `CREATE TABLE #OutputTempTable (Yourcolshere)`. You could also use a table variable `DECLARE @OutputTempTable TABLE (Yourcolshere)`

Answer (score 1):

No answer after 2 years and 2k hits!!!  A simple example to get those of you landing here you started...

Declare table variable to capture merge actions

```
declare @mergeActions table ([action] varchar(10), id int)
```

For OUTPUT clause of MERGE statement...

```
OUTPUT $action as [action] ,inserted.id into @mergeActions;
```